# Hide field properties in command command console when adding columns

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am making a PowerShell Script that creates a list, adds the columns followed by data from the CSV. After finishing the script, our lead told me that I had to get rid of the field properties printing on the console every time a column is added.

```
 CanBeDeleted                : 
 DefaultValue                : 
 Description                 : 
 Direction                   : 
 EnforceUniqueValues         : 
 EntityPropertyName          : 
 Filterable                  : 
 FromBaseType                : 
 Group                       : 
 Hidden                      : 
 Id                          : 
 Indexed                     : 
 InternalName                : 
 JSLink                      : 
 ReadOnlyField               : 
 Required                    : 
 SchemaXml                   : 
 SchemaXmlWithResourceTokens : 
 Scope                       : 
 Sealed                      : 
 Sortable                    : 
 StaticName                  : 
 Title                       : 
 FieldTypeKind               : 
 TypeAsString                : 
 TypeDisplayName             : 
 TypeShortDescription        : 
 ValidationFormula           : 
 ValidationMessage           : 
 Context                     : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext
 Tag                         : 
 Path                        : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ObjectPathMethod
 ObjectVersion               : 
 ServerObjectIsNull          : 
 TypedObject                 : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Field
```

I've been looking online for resources but I can't seem to figure out the right question to ask. Thank you!

Comment: something something | Out-Null

Comment: Without seeing your code, its pretty much impossible to guess what the problem is.

Comment: The Add method of the Fields collection is a very likely culprit. Try something like list.Fields.Add (...) | Out-Null